# Is this zero knowledge protocol for honest verifiers?

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, modular-arithmetic, prime-numbers

Assume the **zero knowledge protocol** where the prover knows a $x$ such that: $g^x = h \pmod{p}$.

- The prover chooses a random $t \in \mathbb{Z}^*_m$ and sends $y = g^t \pmod{p}$
- The verifier sends random $c \in \mathbb{Z}^*_m$ and sends it
- The prover calculates $s = t + c + x$ and sends it
- The verifier accepts if and only if $g^s = yg^ch \pmod{p}$

Is this for **honest verifiers**?

### Attempt:

The real transcript is $(t, g^t \pmod{p}, c, t +c+x)$, but I cannot find a simulated transcript $(t, \cdot, c, \cdot)$ that has the the same distribution as the real one. Can you give me some hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can you give me some hints?

It's not a proof of knowledge, as someone without knowledge of $x$ can complete this protocol successfully with an honest verifier.

Hint: what happens if the ignorant prover sends $y = h^{-1}$?

Comment: Then the verifier will choose a $c$ and the prover will send back $s=c$ so that $g^s = h^{-1} g^c h = yg^ch$ and the prover will pass the challenge without knowing $x$ as you said. Can you elaborate on what does that show for the protocol? Does it mean that it's not a zero knowledge protocol or that it's not a zero knowledge protocol for honest verifiers?

Comment: @Paris: it's not a zero knowledge protocol for proof of knowledge of $x$, as you can 'prove' it without knowing $x$